# How do you associate a user with an order-id in google console or developer api

Tags: google-developers-console

I have just published an app, and so far my purchase rate is below 1 per month, so dealing with refund requests, and refunding the correct purchase would be easy.

I am concerned when the rate increases, I may have no way of telling from a "contact the developer" email, which user request is associated with an order-id, and thus be able to refund the correct account.

The android Google Play does not seem to give an order-id so the user can help associate themselves, and the console does not seem to allow association with an email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this reply from google...

> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 2. On the left menu, select Order management. Search full order with order id or email address of user.
> 3. Check the boxes next to the orders you'd like to refund. To refund multiple orders at the same time, make sure you select orders placed
>      by the same user.
> 4. Select the appropriate refund reason.
> 5. Select Submit.

So given I knew the email address of one of the customers, I was able to search for exactly that customer, and it highlighted the transactions made by that user.

It didn't seem to cope with wildcards, or partial matches (makes sense given privacy).